# Android Retrofit2 need to send request as Key-value but the value is a json, is it possible

Tags: android

Like here json is the key and the value part is a json, 
how to achieved this?

```
json:{"id": "1234","services": [{ "service_id": "123","name": "abc"},"service_id": "123","name": "abc"}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but I think following should be sufficient (assuming you have retrofit configured to use `gson` converter).

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String id;
    private List<Map<String, String>> services;

    ...
}
```

Comment: @Amit could you clarify what you're looking for?  I ran some sample code using the POJO I have above and json matched exactly what you have.

Answer (score 0):

For sending request parameters in key value pairs use HashMap.
Here your HashMap would be like this.

```
HashMap< String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("json",YourPojo);
```

YourPojo.java

```
public class YourPojo{

    private String id;
    private List<Services> services;

    //other fields
    //getters and setters

        //Inner class
        public class Services{

             public String service_id;
             public String name;

             //Getters and setters
        }
}
```

and then put your hashmap as a request parameter in retrofit.
Hope this helps!.